# Pascal's triangle using tikz-pgf: Missing semicolons

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried several semicolons, but I don't know where to set them. I know that one at the very end of the node is ok, but it doesn't work when I'm trying to set it there. I am new to `pgfplots`. Can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\binomtree}[2]{
    \newcounter{one}
    \newcounter{two}
    \setcounter{one}{#1}
    \setcounter{two}{#2}
    \addtocounter{one}{-1}
    \addtocounter{two}{-1}
    \node[circle,draw](z){$\binom{#1}{#2}$}
        \ifnum#1<1%
            child[missing]{}
        \else
            child{\binomtree{\value{one}}{\value{two}}}
        \fi
        \ifnum#2<1%
            child[missing]{}
        \else
            child{\binomtree{\value{one}}{#2}}
        \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\binomtree{7}{5}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**:
I did what commented and have the new problem that it doesn't recognise the given numbers as numbers.

To explain: I am trying to visualise [the recursive solving of binoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Pascal.27s_triangle) like it is presented in [pascals triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Pascal.27s_triangle).

```
\newcommand{\resttree}[2]{
    \setcounter{one}{#1}
    \setcounter{two}{#2}
    \addtocounter{one}{-1}
    \addtocounter{two}{-1}
    node[circle,draw](#1#2){$\binom{#1}{#2}$};
        \ifnum#1<1%
            child[missing]{}
        \else
            child{\resttree{\value{one}}{\value{two}}}
        \fi
        \ifnum#2<1%
            child[missing]{}
        \else
            child{\resttree{\value{one}}{#2}}
        \fi;
}
\newcommand{\binomtree}[2]{
    \newcounter{one}
    \newcounter{two}
    \setcounter{one}{#1}
    \setcounter{two}{#2}
    \addtocounter{one}{-1}
    \addtocounter{two}{-1}
    \node[circle,draw](#1#2){$\binom{#1}{#2}$};
        \ifnum#1<1%
            child[missing]{}
        \else
            child{\resttree{\value{one}}{\value{two}}}
        \fi
        \ifnum#2<1%
            child[missing]{}
        \else
            child{\resttree{\value{one}}{#2}}
        \fi;
}
```

Comment: add ";" here:  `\node[circle,draw](z){$\binom{#1}{#2}$};` and here: `\fi;`. However, you seem to be creating an endless loop here, by calling`\binomtree` inside itself over and over, resulting in another error. What kind of output are you expecting here?

Comment: thank you! after refactoring the counters outside the command it says `Missing number, treated as zero.` at `\binomtree{7}{5}`. $ doesn't help. Do you have a clue why?
@RunarTrollet i am decreasing the numbers until all children are `[missing]`

Comment: why are you writing `\value{one}`? isn't `1` enough? I have no idea what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @RunarTrollet: `one` is the name of a counter and can have an arbitrary number ;-) it is set to 7 (later 7–1=6) in the above example … and `\value` reads the integer value independent of how the counter looks (i.e. what `\theone` prints out), e.g. a,b,c,… or I, II, II,–

Comment: @Tobi I must be tired or something. I completely overlooked the `\newcounter`. Sorry.

Comment: so, any ideas on this missing numbers error?

Comment: The code is not correct in various instances: In the children you are using `\newcounter` again. You use `\node` again in the children (I believe it only accepts the path operator `node`). You use (maybe) unexpanded TeX code on a TikZ path. Minor: You name a node more then once `z`.

Comment: There are also easier ways to set up a loop than this. By the way, you don't seem to be using `pgfplots`, so being new to *that* is probably not the problem ;). There are also better ways to automate trees.

Comment: @cfr do you have an example or a link to something where I can get information about that?

Comment: i think a description of what you are trying to accomplish is essential for others to guide you.

Comment: its visualizing the [recursive solving of binoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Pascal.27s_triangle). On the [german wikipedia site](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomialkoeffizient#Rekursive_Darstellung_und_Pascalsches_Dreieck) you can also see the pascal triangle written in binoms.

Comment: Take a look at `forest` and take a look at the section on 'repeating things' in the TikZ manual. You seem to have an L3 answer already ....

Comment: Actually, I tried to come up with something in Forest but I don't really know what I'm trying to do and I think I was not trying to do the right thing. Forest would definitely be the way I'd go for this. Since you know what you want (presumably), you are in a better position to figure out a strategy than I am without more information, anyway.

Comment: OK. Now I've seen what's wanted, I finished my Forest answer and posted it below. If you simply want to draw the trees, Mark's answer is far and away simpler. However, if you need or wish to highlight or annotate them, Forest may have advantages. I've included an example demonstrating a couple of the possibilities here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion on how this could be done using `expl3`. You can use `\doBinom{8}` and set the number to your needs. It can also solve a binom using `\solveBinom{7}{5}`, see the output.

### Expl3

`expl3` uses some development code from the LaTeX3-project, but it is regarded as very stable. The syntax might look a bit different, and perhaps a bit terrifying at first, but after using it for a short while it becomes very logical. The naming scheme is perhaps what is most different from regular LaTeX, so it does require some explanation. The commands themselves are a lot like what you might expect from most other modern languages.

#### Naming Scheme

The naming scheme is explained well in the documentation of `expl3`, which is quite short and worth a read if you are interested.

I will here write a very brief explanation of some of the code I've used. The commands themselves are further commented in the full code at the bottom of the post.

In the following code, there are only a few functions, all for integers. These start with `\int_` and followed by the description of the command. For instance

```
\int_compare:nNnTF {#1} < {#2} {true} {false}
```

is a `compare`-function. After the `:`, a series of letters follow. How many letters here, tell you how many arguments the command should take. This one takes five arguments. The letters themselves are different ways of setting how the input should be treated concerning expansion, which is much easier with `expl3`. `TF` here is for True and False-code. `n` is braced arguments,  `N` is without braces. This is a bit of a simplification, see documentation.

For variables, the naming scheme is very similar.

```
\l_tmpa_int
```

`\l` means that it is a local variable, in contrast to a global variable. `_tmpa` is the description, and `_int` is the type of the variable, integer. Usually, one would also use a module name for variables, as well as new `expl3`-functions, but I've just used a temporary variable here.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Prints a complete row of binoms
\NewDocumentCommand{\doBinomRow}{mO{0}o}{
    % Specify a command which takes the following input:
    % #1: Mandatory ( m ), the row, n-number
    % #2: Optional, with default value 0 ( O{0} ). Starting k-number
    % #3: Optional ( o ). Ending k-number
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {#2}% Set counter to value of #2(default is 0}
    \int_do_until:nNnn {\l_tmpb_int} > {\IfNoValueTF{#3}{#1}{#3}} { % repeat until counter is as high as #1, or #3 if specified.
        \( \binom{ #1 }{ \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int } \) % Print the binom, with value from #1 and counter
        \int_incr:N \l_tmpb_int % increase the counter
        }

    }

% Prints all rows to n-number binom
\newcommand{\doBinom}[1]{
    % Specify a command which takes the following input:
    % #1: Mandatory. the row, n-number to print to.
    \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int % set counter to zero
    \int_do_until:nNnn {\l_tmpa_int} > {#1} { % repeat command until counter is as high as #1
        \doBinomRow{\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int } % Send row to print
        \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int\\ % Increase the counter
        }
    }
% Solves a binom
\newcommand{\solveBinom}[2]{
    % Specify a command which takes the following input:
    % #1: Mandatory. n-number to solve
    % #2: Mandatory. k-number to solve
    \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int% set counter to zero
    \int_do_until:nNnn {\l_tmpa_int} > 
    {\int_compare:nNnTF {#1} < {#2} {#1} {#2}} { % repeat command until counter is as high as #1 or #2, just to be safe so we don't print negative values in case user types an odd value.
        \doBinomRow{ \int_eval:n {#1-\l_tmpa_int} }[ \int_eval:n {#2 -\l_tmpa_int } ][#2] % Print the row, with decreasing n-number and starting k-number for each row.
        \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int\\ %Increase the counter.
        }
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{7cm}
    \centering
    \doBinomRow{8}\\
    \doBinomRow{8}[3]\\
    \doBinomRow{8}[3][6]\\[4ex]
    \subcaption{Some different ways to input a row}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{7cm}
    \centering
    \doBinom{5}
    \subcaption{Printing a stack of binoms }
\end{minipage}\vspace*{4ex}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{7cm}
    \centering
    \doBinomRow{7}[5][5]\\
    \doBinomRow{6}[4][5]\\
    \doBinomRow{5}[3][5]\\
    \doBinomRow{4}[2][5]\\
    \doBinomRow{3}[1][5]\\
    \doBinomRow{2}[0][5]\\
    \subcaption{Solving a binom manually}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{7cm}
    \centering
    \solveBinom{7}{5}
    \subcaption{Solving a binom automatically}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain (or comment) the commands definition especially the loop how does it works unrelated to the output desired or maybe provide a (reasonable; not too long and too complexe for a starting) document to learn about such programming?

Comment: I do know nothing about pascal triangle, but is it a normal behaviour that with a value > 10 the obtained shape is no longer a triangle ?

Comment: @SAM no, you are correct. I just didn't think of it. If it is, some additions to the code will be needed, with some space added for values below 10.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation, comparing to other languages Tex even the improvment still have a complicated syntax.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's helping alot! still i wanted to solve a binom like this: (7 5) -> (6 4) + (6 5) -> (5 3) + (5 4) + (5 4) + (5 5) -> ... it is hard to explain...

Comment: `\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n - 1}{k - 1} + \binom{n - 1}{k}`

Comment: @Greaka I've revised the answer to your needs.

Comment: @RunarTrollet man you are good! i was still struggling with the expl3. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 7):

For large values the `x` key may have to changed:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\tikzset{pics/binom/.style={code={
  \foreach \k [evaluate={\i=int(\k-1);}] in {1,...,#1}
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\i}
      \node at (-\i/2+\j, -\i) {$\binom{\i}{\j}$};
}}}
\begin{document}
\centering
\foreach \n in {1, 3, ..., 11}{
  \tikz\pic [x=1.75em, y=1.5em] at (0, -\n*2.5) {binom=\n};
  \\[1em]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is by far simpler. Although it loses the tree structure which is useful if you want to e.g. 'show a path through the tree' or whatever. I don't know if Forest is easier than standard TikZ in that case. My answer is not using Forest's node placement, which is really what it is good at, so maybe it is a bit on the wasteful side.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Forest solution:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,forest}
\forestset{%
  declare count register={nint},
  declare count register={kint},
  declare count={kinth}{0},
  nint'=-1,
  kint'=-1,
  binom tree/.style args={#1:#2}{%
    if nint={-1}{
      nint'=#1,
    }{},
    if kint={-1}{
      kint'=#2,
    }{},
    kinth'=#2,
    content={\binom{#1}{#2}},
    math content,
    if={((nint)>level())&&((kint)>level())}{%
      delay={%
        if={(n()==1)||(level()==0)}{%
          prepend={%
            [, binom tree/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={##1:##2}{int(#1-1)}{int(#2-1)}]
          },
        }{%
          prepend={%
            [, phantom]
          },
        },
          append={%
            [, binom tree/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1:#2}{int(#1-1)}]
          },
      },
    }{},
    for tree={%
      no edge,
      l sep=0pt,
      inner sep=0pt,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        tier/.option=level,
      }
    },
    before computing xy={%
      for tree={%
        l'=\baselineskip,
      },
    },
    before drawing tree={%
      where level=0{}{%
        x/.pgfmath={x("!r")+((kinth()-(kint)+level()/2)*15pt)}
      },
    }
  },
}
\newcommand*\binomtree[2]{%
  \Forest{[, binom tree={#1:#2}]}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [, binom tree={7:5}
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [, binom tree={5:4}
  ]
\end{forest}
\binomtree{6}{3}
\binomtree{6}{5}
\end{document}
```

`\binomtree{}{}` is just a convenience wrapper to save having to invoke the `forest` environment each time. So the first 2 examples above could also be written

```
\binomtree{7}{5}
\binomtree{5}{4}
```

And the output:

[image: 7:5]

[image: 5:4]

[image: 6:3]

[image: 6:5]

The advantage of this method is that you can, by using the `forest` environment version, have access to all of Forest and TikZ's facilities for annotating the tree, should you wish to do this.

For example, suppose we want to label the levels of the tree 0,1,2 and so on. In addition, we'd like to highlight the 'path' from the root of the tree to the terminus corresponding to `\binom{2}{3}`. Then we can say

```
\begin{forest}
  before drawing tree={%
    where={kinth()==(kint)}{%
      tikz+/.wrap pgfmath arg={%
        \node [anchor=east] at ([xshift=-20pt]!rF.west |- .center) {#1:};
      }{level()},
    }{},
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where content={\binom{2}{3}}{%
      for current and ancestors={red},
    }{},
  }
  [, binom tree={7:5}]
\end{forest}
```

[image: annotated example]

Although I created `binom tree` to use the syntax `#1:#2`, you could make it take `{#1}{#2}` if preferred. (In fact, it is more straightforward to do that, if anything.)